# How to configure polling from AWS SQS in Node JS in deployment?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am pretty new to AWS SQS and trying to configure aws sqs where I need to poll every 10-15 mins to receive messages. Below is the code I have for receiving the messages for polling every 10 mins. It is working fine locally but I have to run the command **node receiveMessage.js** and then it starts polling. I have read about long polling as well but our requirement is such we need to poll every 10 mins or so.

MY question is how do I configure this so that it'll start polling when I deploy the changes in gitlab to DEV environment? I have seen other posts using sqs-consumer. But trying to understand how do I confugre that command **node receiveMessage.js** which will start the polling from the DEV environment. Any suggestion ?

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

// Set up AWS credentials and region
AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-east-1' });

// Create an SQS instance
const sqs = new AWS.SQS();

// Specify the URL of the SQS queue
const queueUrl = queueURL;

// Function to poll the SQS queue
const pollQueue = () => {
  const params = {
    QueueUrl: queueUrl,
    MaxNumberOfMessages: 10, // Maximum number of messages to receive in a single API call
    WaitTimeSeconds: 0, // Wait time for long polling (0 for short polling)
  };

  sqs.receiveMessage(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error receiving messages from the queue:', err);
      return;
    }

    // Process received messages
    if (data.Messages && data.Messages.length > 0) {
      data.Messages.forEach((message) => {
        // Process each message as needed
        console.log('Received message:', message.Body);

        // Delete the processed message from the queue
        const deleteParams = {
          QueueUrl: queueUrl,
          ReceiptHandle: message.ReceiptHandle,
        };
        sqs.deleteMessage(deleteParams, (deleteErr) => {
          if (deleteErr) {
            console.log('Error deleting message:', deleteErr);
          }
        });
      });
    }

    // Poll the queue again after 10 minutes
   setTimeout(pollQueue, 10 * 60 * 1000);
   
  });
};

// Start polling the SQS queue
pollQueue();
```

Comment: SQS cannot time the execution of your code which consumes messages. You will need to set a cron, if running on server. Another way is to setup a Lambda which is triggered by EventBridge every 10 minutes. This lambda will pick messages from SQS and process.